# Resize TabItem header size inside TabControl

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, mahapps.metro

I am using `MahApps` `TabControl` and i have several `TabItems`:

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl" FontSize="12">
    <TabItem Header="Statistics" />
</TabControl>
```

I try to change  the `font` size of the `TabControl` and `TabItems` in order to resize my headers but it seems that this not changing anything.

Answer (score 25):

You should use the attached property `HeaderFontSize` to set the header font size of the tav items.

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl">
  <TabItem Header="Statistics" Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize="12" />
</TabControl>
```

or

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl">
  <TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
      <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>
  </TabControl.Resources>
  <TabItem Header="Statistics" />
</TabControl>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it seems this property doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @JobaDiniz It's still available in the ControlsHelper class.

Comment: yeah... V2013 *xaml designer* bad, not mine =D. It wasn't showing it in code completion.

Comment: works like charm. + may need to use Vertical Alignment="Center"

Answer (score 6):

In 2.* versions of MahApps.Metro it changes to:

```xml
<TabControl Name="tabControl">
  <TabItem Header="Statistics" Controls:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontSize="12" />
</TabControl>
```

or

```xml
<TabControl Name="tabControl">
  <TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
      <Setter Property="Controls:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>
  </TabControl.Resources>
  <TabItem Header="Statistics" />
</TabControl>
```

Source: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3711

Documentation is not available at the time of writing.

Answer (score 3):

Put the below code in Window.Resources

```
    <Window
    ......
    xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    ......
    >

<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuLevel2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
        </Style>
<Window.Resources>
```

In the TabItem section add the style details.

```
<TabItem Header="Dimension Alias" Style="{DynamicResource MenuLevel2}">
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

since tabItems is a list of item having some common bindings modifying one of Tabitem header height will automatically do for the others

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem >
     <TabItem.Header>
          <Label Height="30" Content="Main" FontSize="16" >   
          </Label>
     </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem  Header="Second header" >
  <TabItem  Header="Third header" >

</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.0 we have to use this in your *App.xaml* or directly in the resources of your control:

```
<System:Double x:Key="MahApps.Font.Size.TabItem">16.67</System:Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this has solved my problem:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```